# Show WPF tooltip on disabled item only

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, tooltip, ivalueconverter

Just wondering if it is possible to show a WPF on a disabled item *ONLY* (and not when the item is enabled).

I would like to give the user a tooltip explaining why an item is currently disabled.

I have an `IValueConverter` to invert the boolean `IsEnabled` property binding. But it doesn't seem to work in this situation. The `ToolTip` is show both when the item is enabled and disabled.

So is is possible to bind a `ToolTip.IsEnabled` property exclusively to an item's own !`IsEnabled`?

Pretty straightforward question I guess, but code example here anyway:

```
public class BoolToOppositeBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(bool))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

        return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(bool))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

        return !(bool)value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And the binding:

```
<TabItem Header="Tab 2" Name="tabItem2" ToolTip="Not enabled in this situation." ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, ElementName=tabItem2, Converter={StaticResource oppositeConverter}}">
    <Label Content="Item content goes here" />
</TabItem>
```

Thanks folks.

Comment: Are you sure ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" isn't executing "after" your inversion? It seems like only the enabled binding should be necessary.

Comment: @JustABill:

That might be the case but it doesn't work without ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True".

Maybe I need to handle it in code-behind. I'd prefer to keep GUI stuff in XAML if possible.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you bind to Tooltip like ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=tabItem2, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource newconverter}, ConverterParameter=Actual tooltip text goes here}", where newconverter is a new type that returns the value in parameter if the value is true. Or false in your case I guess. (Also I typed that from memory so forgive me if the syntax is off)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

JustABill's suggestion worked. I also needed to define the string as a resource to avoid problems with quotation marks. And you still need to set ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True".

So, here is the working code which shows how to display a tooltip in WPF ***only*** when an item is disabled.

In the top container, include the system namespace (see *sys* below). I also have a Resources namespace, which I called "Res".

```
    <Window x:Class="MyProjectName.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:Res="clr-namespace:MyProjectName.Resources"
    >
```

Then you need

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Res:FalseToStringConverter x:Key="falseToStringConv" />
    <sys:String x:Key="stringToShowInTooltip">This item is disabled because...</sys:String>
</Window.Resources>
```

In my case, it was a tab item that I was interested in. It could be any UI element though...

```
<TabItem Name="tabItem2" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" ToolTip="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, ElementName=tabItem2, Converter={StaticResource falseToStringConv}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource stringToShowInTooltip}}">
            <Label Content="A label in the tab" />
</TabItem>
```

And the converter in code behind (or wherever you want to put it). Note, mine went into the a namespace called *Resources*, which was declared earlier.

```
public class FalseToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool && parameter is string)
        {
            if ((bool)value == false)
                return parameter.ToString();
            else return null;
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The value must be a boolean and parameter must be a string");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 19):

A little out of date, but I got this working by setting RelativeSource mode to Self instead of setting the ElementName within the Binding.

```
<TabItem Header="Tab 2" Name="tabItem2" ToolTip="Not enabled in this situation." ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Converter={StaticResource oppositeConverter}}">
    <Label Content="Item content goes here" />
</TabItem>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems much simpler than the accepted solution!